# Update colPos with typo3 extension flux 9.0.1

Tags: mysql, typo3, flux

Since the update flux to 9.0.1 I need to update the colPos of elements.

This works fine:

```
UPDATE `tt_content` 
SET colPos = ((tx_flux_parent * 100) + 11) 
WHERE tx_flux_column = "content";
```

But I need also to update the localized content elements. It have in tx_flux_parent the localized parent uid. But I need the parent uid of the standard language.

I need to get the value "tx_flux_parent" in tt_content by l18n_parent. 
So I'm trying to build a query with l18n_parent like this:

```
UPDATE `tt_content` as t1 
SET colPos = (( (SELECT t2.tx_flux_parent 
                 FROM tt_content t2 
                 WHERE t1.l18n_parent = t2.uid) * 100) + 11) 
WHERE t1.tx_flux_column = "content";
```

And get this:

> MySQL meldet: Dokumentation 1093 - Table 't1' is specified twice, both
>   as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: MySQL does not allow referencing the table being updated in a subquery inside `IN()` clause etc. But your pseudocode has another issues. What if there are multiple rows received from your subquery ?

Comment: Yes I updated the code. How it is possible to get an value from subquery (parent) and set it in the child row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not allow referencing the table *being updated* again in another subquery, **unless** it is inside the `FROM` clause ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)).

However, in this particular case, you can rather use "Self-Join":

```
UPDATE `tt_content` as t1 
JOIN `tt_content` as t2 
  ON t1.l18n_parent = t2.uid 
SET t1.colPos = ((t2.tx_flux_parent * 100) + 11) 
WHERE t1.tx_flux_column = 'content'
```