# UPDATE statement using the same table in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

```
SELECT
    vl1.phone_number,
    vl1.first_name,
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(
            (
            SELECT
                vl2.phone_number 
            FROM
                list as vl2
            WHERE
                vl2.phone_number LIKE CONCAT( SUBSTRING( vl1.phone_number FROM 1 FOR 3 ), "%" ) 
            ORDER BY
                RAND( ) 
                LIMIT 1 
            ) 
        FROM
            1 FOR 6 
        ),
        FLOOR( RAND( ) * ( 8999 ) ) + 1000 
    ) AS autogenNumber 
FROM
    list as vl1
LIMIT 1
```

The results I get are

```
phone_number | firstname | autogenNumber
```

The autogenNumber is generated by first searching for other numbers that share the first three digits. Then 6 digits from that number are picked and another 4 random digits are subsituted to the end.

The above sql query generates the autogen number exactly as I need it.

However, now the issue arises when I want to update the column security_phrase in this list using the similar query below.

```
UPDATE list as vl1
SET vl1.security_phrase = (
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(
            (
                SELECT
                    vl2.phone_number 
                FROM
                    list AS vl2 
                WHERE
                    vl2.phone_number LIKE CONCAT( SUBSTRING(phone_number FROM 1 FOR 3 ), "%" ) 
                ORDER BY
                    RAND( ) 
                    LIMIT 1 
                ) 
            FROM
                1 FOR 6 
            ),
            FLOOR( RAND( ) * ( 8999 ) ) + 1000 
        ) 
    ) 
    LIMIT 10
```

Gives me an error:

> 1093 - Table 'vl1' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE'
>   and as a separate source for data

I have also tried

```
UPDATE list AS vl1
JOIN list AS vl2 

SET vl1.security_phrase = (
    CONCAT( SUBSTRING( vl2.phone_number FROM 1 FOR 6 ), FLOOR( RAND( ) * ( 8999 ) ) + 1000 ) 
) 
WHERE
    vl2.phone_number LIKE CONCAT( SUBSTRING( vl1.phone_number FROM 1 FOR 3 ), "%" )
```

Not working and does not give the intended results...

Any help

Comment: Check this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53502117/2469308

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks, will try and get back in a couple of minutes

Comment: See my latest query but the issue is that I can't do a JOIN on a particular column....

Comment: Can you explain with some sample data and corresponding expected output on what you are trying to achieve. Your query involves lots of string operations; I am thinking maybe there is simpler way around.

Comment: Trying to set the security_phrase for each record in list to autogennumber. The autogenNumber is generated by first searching for other phone_numbers that share the first three digits. Then 6 digits from that searched phone_numbers list is randomly picked. Another 4 random digits are substituted to the end.

Comment: Is there a Primary key in your table ? We will have to use Derived tables for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184332/discussion-between-vish-and-madhur-bhaiya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not allow referencing the table *being updated* again in another subquery, **unless** it is inside the `FROM` clause ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)).

Now, in your particular case, we will need to put the complete `SELECT` query block as a Derived Table. As discussed in chat, `lead_id` is your Primary Key, so we will join back using the PK to update the rows accordingly.

```
UPDATE list AS t1 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    vl1.lead_id,
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(
            (
            SELECT
                vl2.phone_number 
            FROM
                list as vl2
            WHERE
                vl2.phone_number LIKE CONCAT( SUBSTRING( vl1.phone_number FROM 1 FOR 3 ), "%" ) 
            ORDER BY
                RAND( ) 
                LIMIT 1 
            ) 
        FROM
            1 FOR 6 
        ),
        FLOOR( RAND( ) * ( 8999 ) ) + 1000 
    ) AS autogenNumber 
  FROM
    list as vl1
) AS dt 
  ON dt.lead_id = t1.lead_id 
SET t1.security_phrase = dt.autogenNumber
```

Comment: Is there a way that you can make this faster...At the moment it does around 100 records every 7 seconds.

Comment: @Vish I doubt it can be made faster; because of RAND(), there is full table scan involved everytime. Is RAND() necessary ?

Comment: I know, is there no alternative way to simulate rand() but faster? Rand means that when security phrase is updated it the digits 3-6 are picked from a random phone_number while still matching the first three digits

Comment: @Vish I understand why RAND() is necessary for security purposes. One way is to execute the query via an application code. Do it in batches. If the Table is InnoDB, you can infact have multiple concurrent applications setup, accessing different lead_id(s) to update.

Comment: @Vish also add Index on `lead_id, phone_number`

Comment: Still slow.... can i do something like WHERE RAND() < (SELECT 
                ((Row_limit_count / COUNT(phone_number)) * 10)